# How to scope to self?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

We have a web service that uses a Unit-of-Work pattern. The Unit-of-Work pattern needs to use the same `DbContext` in several places. So our first idea was to scope the `dbContext` to the request scope, like so:

```
kernel.Bind<IStore>().ToConstructor<TestContext>(_ => new TestContext(Env.DbServerInstance, databaseName)).InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<DbContextUnitOfWork>();
```

Which worked just fine, until we needed to use two Unit-of-Work objects within the same Request Scope. Ops! We got back an error stating that the DbContext has already be disposed.

The `InRequestScope` almost worked, therefore we think that we need to move the scoping rule from the `dbContext` and apply some type of scoping rule the the `IUnitOfWork` object instead. Here is our current attempt:

```
kernel.Bind<IStore>().ToConstructor<TestContext>(_ => new TestContext(Env.DbServerInstance, databaseName));
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<DbContextUnitOfWork>().InScope(ctx =>
        {
            return ctx.???;
        });
```

But how do we access the instantiated DbContextUnitOfWork from the ctx context object? We can access the `DbContextUnitOfWork` type (from `ctx.Request.Service`) but that doesn't seem to help us. In other words, I would like something like this:

```
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<DbContextUnitOfWork>().InSelfScope();
```

Or is there a better way to achieve our desired out come?

**Update**

@Luke McGregor - Yes, the `IUnitOfWork` consumes the `IStore` interface. I've also read about the [Captive Dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/) you suggested - thanks. However, in our case the `IUnitOfWork` is the root node to our object graph, and we only want a single instance of the `IStore` **per instance** of each `IUnitOfWork`.

For example: let's say that the UnitOfWork (call it service A) depends on Services B and C and these two services require an IStore (service D) then services B and C *must* share the same instance of service D. (As if service D is a singleton from service A's point of view.) Therefore, if I create two instances of UnitOfWork (A1 and A2) then the system should only contain two instances of service D (ie. D1 and D2).

Also, when A1 is disposed of, it's entire object graph is also disposed of, likewise with A2.

Here a diagram of what we are trying to achieve.

[image]

Thus, A1's object graph is completely independent of A2's object graph yet, service D acts like a singleton within each of the respective object graphs.

So, how would we configure the IUnitOfWork and/or the IStore to make this work? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging, we found exactly what we was looking for.

The [Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.namedscope) extension provides several new scoping rules, one of these is called the `InNamedScope` and it appears to be working perfectly for our needs.

Answer (score 0):

You always need to scope a consumer in a [lower or equal scope than its dependencies](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/)*.

For example if you have your context bound in request scope your IUnitOfWork thing (which i assume consumes IStore) should be bound in request scope or transient scope.

Any consumers of the IUnitOfWork also need to be bound in request scope or lower (I imagine this is the bit you are missing, something is probably thread or singleton scope somewhere).

*Transient scope is a bit of an exception to this rule as its scoped by the consumer. EG it will be disposed at the end of the scope of the thing its injected into.